# Angular 2 using ngUI map

Tags: angularjs, angular, ionic2

Here is something I tried

This is my code:

```
<ngui-map center="Brampton, Canada">
    <marker position="Brampton, Canada" 
      draggable="true" 
      (click)="clicked($event)">
    </marker>
    <info-window id="iw">
      lat: [[lat]], lng: [[lng]]
    </info-window>
  </ngui-map>

import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NguiMapComponent } from '@ngui/map';
  @Component({
    template: require('./app.html')
  })
  class AppCompoment {
    clicked(event) {
      let marker = event.target;
      marker.ng2MapComponent.openInfoWindow('iw', marker, {
        lat: marker.getPosition().lat(), 
        lng: marker.getPosition().lng(),
      });
    }
```

I am getting this error:

```
Cannot read property 'openInfoWindow' of undefined
```

How can I fix this issue.

Kindly advice me.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try using `@ViewChild` to access the child component.

```
<ngui-map center="Brampton, Canada">
    <marker #mrker position="Brampton, Canada" 
      draggable="true" 
      (click)="clicked($event)"><!-- set id -->
    </marker>
    <info-window id="iw">
      lat: [[lat]], lng: [[lng]]
    </info-window>
  </ngui-map>
```

Component Class:

```
import { Component,ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { NguiMapComponent } from '@ngui/map';
  @Component({
    template: require('./app.html')
  })
  class AppCompoment {
   @ViewChild(NguiMapComponent)
   ngMap:NguiMapComponent;

   //@ViewChild('mrker')
   //marker:any;

    clicked(event) {
      let marker = event.target;
      this.ngMap.openInfoWindow('iw', marker, {
        lat: marker.getPosition().lat(), 
        lng: marker.getPosition().lng(),
      });
    }
```

Comment: Thanks.I getting this err this.marker.getPosition is not a function

Comment: am not sure of the api... console log marker and check

Comment: I dont understand...ur question

Comment: you originally used event.target to get marker from the view. was that working?console log event.target

Comment: I consoled event.target value is _.Ne{__gm: Object, gm_accessors_: Object, draggable: true, gm_bindings_: Object, clickable: true…}.But i still getting this err Cannot read property 'openInfoWindow' of undefined

Comment: found [this plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/6e1qWK?p=preview) in the [official github](https://github.com/ng2-ui/map).

Comment: Ya.I also refer this.Bt i have no idea.. : (

Answer (score 0):

```
<ngui-map zoom="14" [center]="center"  (mapClick)="onMapClick($event)">
  <marker *ngFor="let pos of positions"
          [position]="pos" (click)="clickedMarker($event)" ></marker>
  <info-window id="iw">
    <div *ngIf="infoposition">

      lat: {{ position.coords.latitude }}, lng: {{ position.coords.longitude }}
    </div>

  </info-window>


</ngui-map>




 clickedMarker(event:any) {
let marker = event.target;
let lat = marker.getPosition().lat();
let lng= marker.getPosition().lng();
marker.nguiMapComponent.openInfoWindow('iw', marker);
```

}

Comment: kindly add an explanation as to what changes you made